# Thread swaps in and out automatically without any yield or sleep

Tags: java, multithreading

I thought a thread only gives up its domination(control?) when we wrote something like yield, sleep inside the run method. The output of the following code I am expected to see is something like :

```
#1(5), #1(4), #1(3), #1(2), #1(1), #2(5), #2(4), #2(3), #2(2), #2(1), #3(5), #3(4), #3(3), #3(2), #3(1), #4(5), #4(4), #4(3), #4(2), #4(1), #5(5), #5(4), #5(3), #5(2), #5(1)
```

however, it turns out like all the thread are running at the same time.
the output:

```
#4(5), #2(5), #1(5), #1(4), #1(3), #1(2), #1(1), #3(5), #5(5), #3(4), #2(4), #2(
3), #4(4), #2(2), #3(3), #3(2), #5(4), #3(1), #2(1), #4(3), #4(2), #4(1), #5(3),
 #5(2), #5(1)
```

I am so confused.

```
public class SimpleThread extends Thread {
  private int countDown = 5;
  private static int threadCount = 0;
  public SimpleThread() {
    // Store the thread name:
    super(Integer.toString(++threadCount));
    start();
  }
  public String toString() {
    return "#" + getName() + "(" + countDown + "), ";
  }
  public void run() {
    while(true) {
      System.out.print(this);
      if(--countDown == 0)
        return;
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      new SimpleThread();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I thought a thread only gives up its domination(control?) when we wrote something like yield, sleep inside the run method.

Nope, not at all. Threads run in parallel, each executing concurrently with all other threads. It is common to get garbled output when you print to `System.out` from several threads at the same time.

It hasn't been necessary for threads or processes to explicitly yield control since the Windows 3.x days when the operating system used cooperative multitasking. UNIX operating systems use preemptive multitasking, as does every version of Windows since Windows 95. Preemptive multitasking means the operating system can suspend a thread at any point, for example when it's used up its time slice.

Having threads run in parallel is what enables programs to take advantage of the multi-core architectures that are common today. If only one thread could run at a time there'd be no benefit to having more than one CPU.

Comment: then what is the point to use the yield() since they are all going to run in parallel. . I was thinking the thread is running one by one.. thus you use yield or something to stops it for a moment and gives other threads a little time to execute which we achieve concurrency.

Comment: `Thread.yield()` is not very useful. It's almost always a mistake. I've never seen a good use for it in practice. The OS can schedule threads perfectly fine without your help. A common mistake is to have a loop waiting for some variable to change, and so you try to play nice and use `yield()` so as not to hog the CPU: `while (!ready) Thread.yield();` This comment box does not have enough room for me to explain the many reasons this is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

According to the specification thread execution order is not guaranteed. Thus you cannot expect that started thread will be finished before second starts.

According to Kathy Sierra oca/ocp java se 7 book (OCA/OCP Java SE 7 Programmer I & II Study Guide):

> The thread scheduler is the part of the JVM (although most JVMs map Java threads
>   directly to native threads on the underlying OS) that decides which thread should
>   run at any given moment, and also takes threads out of the run state. Assuming a
>   single processor machine, only one thread can actually run at a time. Only one stack
>   can ever be executing at one time. And it's the thread scheduler that decides which
>   thread—of all that are eligible—will actually run. When we say eligible, we really
>   mean in the runnable state.
>   Any thread in the runnable state can be chosen by the scheduler to be the one and
>   only running thread. If a thread is not in a runnable state, then it cannot be chosen to be
>   the currently running thread. And just so we're clear about how little is guaranteed here:
>   The order in which runnable threads are chosen to run is not guaranteed.
>   Although queue behavior is typical, it isn't guaranteed. Queue behavior means
>   that when a thread has finished with its "turn," it moves to the end of the line of the
>   runnable pool and waits until it eventually gets to the front of the line, where it can
>   be chosen again. In fact, we call it a runnable pool, rather than a runnable queue, to
>   help reinforce the fact that threads aren't all lined up in some guaranteed order

Answer (score 0):

How your threads are scheduled to run largely depend on the underlying OS and hardware. The OS decides when your threads get to execute and in what order.

For example, if you have multiple cores on your machine, the OS will likely try to run your threads concurrently (at the same time).

Even if you only have one core the OS will most likely try to be fair and give all your threads some time to execute since they have the same priority.

Comment: so there is no different on writing yield() or just leave it like that?

Comment: @LuXiaoming using yield() is quite pointless. It is a hint that the current threads is willing to yield it use of the CPU. However, threads will typically be preempted many many times per second anyways.