# Java Threads work frequency

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to load some files while I display a 'loading animated text'.

I use one thread for load files, and my main thread for display the animation.

The problem is that during some tests, I noticed that the **working time used by my threads** are so **bad** some times that my **animation is really freezed**.

**code exemple** : this is an exemple my code is too long but here is the main form of my code for loading files :

```
for (int i = 0; i < file.size; i++) {
     //Do soem stuff
}
```

**exemple : (A = loading file thread; B = text animation)**

```
A
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
A
A
A
A
A
```

**What I would like :**

```
A
 B
A
A
 B
 B
A
A
 B
A
 B
A
 B
A
```

**My question is** : Is there a way to make a threads work more simultaneous ?

**Edit** :

My code is too long (more than 500 lines) but doing a simple code I get the same bad results :

exemple

```
package thread_test;

public class TestThread extends Thread {


  public TestThread(String name) {
    super(name);
  }

  public void run() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        System.out.println(this.getName());
  }       
}
```

---

Main class

```
package thread_test;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    TestThread t = new TestThread("A");
    TestThread t2 = new TestThread(" B");

    t.start();
    t2.start();

}

}
```

result :

```
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
 B
```

As you can see I face the same problem, so if we can solve this one with the given code, I think I could solve mine.

Comment: You can always limit the amount of work that they do in one cycle. If you use a counter that increments at every action, you can easily make such a construction. What I'm trying to say is that you can check the value of the counter, and if it's at or above a specific value, you can call sleep() on the thread. Threads have complex discipline algorithms, and it's hard to say which will execute when. Another thing that you can try is to offload the main thread. Start two threads for the tasks, having a total of 3 now.

Comment: Thraed scheduling is AFAIR done by your OS.

Comment: Without seeing how you create and start the threads, your file handling and you animation, it's tough to give an answer.  There are many variables associated with concurrency.

Comment: You can also play with thread priorities.  But I completely agree with MadConan, we can't give proper recommendations without seeing some concrete code.  Normally, the OS does a decent job of giving every thread a fair slice of the CPU time.  But maybe something in your code is preventing that, but we can't see it.

Comment: It also depends on the algorithm that is used by the OS. If the threads are very short to complete, there is a very large chance that they will finish within a quantum.

Comment: I have edited my post, for more informations @MadConan

Comment: Based on what little you have given, I'm going to guess you have a [busy-wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) loop that's eating all your CPU.

Comment: You're trying to even out two IO operations. You won't ever get what you want.

Comment: @sturcotte06 can you explain ? and the code showed in my edit is from a website and they said we should see A then B then A then B, etc. frequently, I don't understand why they don't switch each other.

Comment: Mainly because you can't predict IO operations. Also, threads don't switch to each other, the operating system schedule them based on a set of rules. Don't try to predict multithreaded scenario, it leads to bad designs.

Comment: @LeSam Well, they were wrong. Short threads (and there are few things shorter than printing the same string 30 times) are likely to execute fully in one go. And if you've got multiple CPUs, things get even stranger.

Comment: It was good to try to simplify the example, but the scheduling of threads will depend to some extent on what they are really doing. What is your animation thread really doing? (That is, does it really print to stdout, or is it using some GUI library to draw, or what?) Does it interact with the file loading thread, for example to receive updates on progress? I don't see any reason why the animation would freeze on a multi-processor system, short of a programming error. So to understand better, you'll have to provide a bit more detail in your question.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to Thread scheduling, very little is guaranteed in Java: For example the order in which Threads are chosen from the threadpool to run is not guaranteed.

You can not control the scheduler, but you can influence it, e.g. by using

- [Thread.yield()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield%28%29) as a hint to the scheduler to "let some other thread do some work"
- [Thread.sleep(long)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) to let the current thread sleep at least for the specified amount of time
- Use [Thread.setPriority(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority%28int%29) to set different thread priorities (but keep in mind that thread-scheduling priority behaviour is not guaranteed by the JVM)
- or you enforce a stricter lifecycle control of your threads using [Thread.join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29), *synchronization*, [Object.wait()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) and [Object.notify()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29) / [Object.notifyAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll%28%29)

If the Thread lifecycle is as described by you (i.e. both threads are getting the same amount of time but should switch more often), try adding some [Thread.yield()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield%28%29) to both threads.

But in most cases when the scheduler does *strange* things, the problem is that there is a single thread that nearly takes all of the cpu time.

Answer (score 2):

*(A bit of a long post, but I hope it helps you understand what is going on)*

Well, as some of the comments have already hinted, it's hard to observe interleaving thread execution for such a small sample of code that executes so quickly.

It's not impossible though, especially on a multi-CPU/core machine, you may still be able to observe some parallel execution for your sample.  But you'll have to run it multiple times, and maybe you'll get lucky.

Intuitively, when we think of parallel executing threads, we have a desire to think that each thread gets to run one line of code only before yielding execution to another thread.

But that's not how the OS schedules threads for execution at all.  In fact, it would be a bad idea to do that, because there is a significant performance cost every time the OS switches contexts to allow a different thread to execute.  So, instead, the way the OS implements parallel execution is by giving each thread X amount of time before another thread gets a turn to execute. This allotted time slice is what is referred to as a `quantum`.  And a thread can execute as many lines of code as it wants without any interruption (from other threads) as long as it can run them within that allotted time slice or quantum.  When the time is up, the OS switches the execution context to allow another thread to execute. (This is a very simplified explanation, but hopefully it helps you to get the basic idea)

To see why it makes sense to perform parallel execution this way, instead of switching threads for every line of execution, let's consider the following, using completely bogus numbers (and to simplify things, let's assume we have a single CPU. It gets more complicated with more):

- Let's say that every line of execution takes 1 ms to run.
- Let's say we have thread `A` that has 1000 lines of code to execute (1000 ms of work)
- Let's say we have thread `B` that only has 100 lines of code to execute (100 ms of work)
- And finally, let's say that it takes 10 ms for the OS to perform a context switch (switch execution from one thread to another)

What are the different ways we could have the threads perform the work?

**Option 1: Allow threads to completely finish their work before switching to another thread**

1. Execute thread `A` to completion: this takes 1000 ms.
2. Switch context to allow thread `B` to execute: this takes 10 ms.
3. Execute thread `B` to completion: this takes 100 ms.

***Total execution time: 1110 ms.***  Very good time.

Not bad! However, from the perspective of someone observing thread `B`, it looked like the thread froze for a second before finally doing anything.  So the perception was probably somewhat negative.

Now let's examine the other extreme...

**Option 2: Each thread gets to execute a single line of code before switching to another thread (similar to what you are asking in your post)**

Executed 100x in a loop:

1. Execute one line of code from thread `A`: 1 ms.
2. Switch context to allow thread `B` to execute: this takes 10 ms.
3. Execute one line of code from thread `B`: 1 ms.
4. Switch context to allow thread `A` to execute: this takes 10 ms.

At this point, thread `B` is finished, and this has taken a total of 2200 ms already.  And now, we still have to run the rest of thread `A`'s work, which is 900 ms more.

So we have a grand total of: ***3100 ms of execution time.***

Clearly, this was not nearly as optimal as the first option.  And keep in mind that this example pretends that we only have these 2 threads running.  But in the real world, these 2 threads are part of a much larger pool of threads running from all kinds of other processes.  and the OS has to be fair to those threads too.  So if the OS used this approach to execute threads in parallel, you can see the amount of wasted time that would occur because of all those context switches.

However, from the perspective of someone observing thread `B`, at least it seemed like it was never frozen.  It was very, very slow, but never frozen.  So, does that mean we have a happy user?  Probably not.

And finally, let's examine the typical approach a OS will use:

**Option 2: Each thread gets a fixed time slice or quantum**

Let's say the OS has predetermined a quantum to be 50 ms. (In our example using bogus measurements, this would mean that each thread gets to execute 50 lines of code uninterrupted) Then the parallel execution of both threads will look something like this:

1. Execute thread `A` for 50 ms.
2. Switch to thread `B`: 10 ms.
3. Execute thread `B` for 50 ms.
4. Switch to thread `A`: 10 ms.
5. Execute thread `A` for 50 ms.
6. Switch to thread `B`: 10 ms.
7. Execute thread `B` for 50 ms. <-- thread B is finished here.
8. Switch to thread `A`: 10 ms.
9. Execute thread `A` for 900 ms.

***Total execution time: 1140 ms.***

So, as you can see, the total execution time is much much better than trying to interleave threads with each line of execution.  Yet, by dividing the work in time slices, none of the threads ever stopped working for longer than 60 ms, which is such a small number, that from the user's perspective, it felt like thread `B` never froze.

So, basically, the OS is doing its best to find a sweet middle ground between providing good total execution times, and yet providing a responsive user experience.  And it does this by setting an appropriate quantum size.  How big is a quantum?  Well, that varies a lot depending on a lot of factors and OSes, and the value can usually be tweaked, if you really, really must. (More on that at the very end of this post)  But my understanding is that typical quantum values can vary somewhere between 20 ms to upwards of 100 ms, again, depending on many factors.

**Conclusion**

Hopefully, you now understand ***how*** the OS schedules threads by using time slices, ***why*** it does it the way it does, and why you didn't observe thread interleaving in your short sample program.

But to drive home the point, the amount of code that you had to run in each thread was so small and so quick to execute, that it fit entirely in a single quantum or time slice.  So the OS didn't bother interrupting thread `A` because it felt it wasn't worth the cost to perform the context switch.

That said, on larger programs, where each thread has a lot more work to perform, then finding that right balance between good actual performance and perceived performance can become a concern.

Normally, OSes do a good job of prioritizing threads that are responsible for displaying things to the user.  Still, if truly necessary, there are usually ways to change the quantum settings to change the balance a bit.

One example of this in the Windows OS, is in the `My PC` -> `Properties` -> `Advanced system settings` -> `Advanced tab` -> `Performance settings...`. There you get to pick between `Adjust for best appearance` and `Adjust for best performance`.  And as you can no doubt guess by now, this setting tweaks the quantum size under the covers to adjust the thread execution balance.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have added Thread.sleep(1) and output is some what like you are want

Try this run method :

```
  public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        System.out.println(this.getName());
        try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

And Output is :

```
A
 B
 B
A
 B
A
 B
A
 B
A
 B
A
A
 B
A
 B
A
 B
A
 B
A
 B
 B
A
 B
A
 B
A
A
 B
 B
A
A
 B
 B
A
 B
A
A
 B
A
 B
 B
A
A
 B
A
 B
A
 B
 B
A
 B
A
A
 B
 B
A
A
 B
```

Reason why this will work is i have given Thread.sleep(1) so that will sleep the current thread and gives other a change to execute and same will happen with other thread.

> **Note** : The thread scheduler is the part of the JVM  that
>   decides which thread should run at any given moment, and also takes
>   threads out of the run state.  Any thread in the
>   runnable state can be chosen by the scheduler to be in
>   running thread.  The order in which runnable
>   threads are chosen to run is not guaranteed. Although queue behavior
>   is typical, it isn't guaranteed. Queue behavior means that when a
>   thread has finished with its "turn," it moves to the end of the line
>   of the runnable pool and waits until it eventually gets to the front
>   of the line, where it can be chosen again. In fact, we call it a
>   runnable pool, rather than a runnable queue, to help reinforce the
>   fact that threads aren't all lined up in some guaranteed order

Above Note is From This Stackoverflow question : *[Thread swaps in and out automatically without any yield or sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30427745/thread-swaps-in-and-out-automatically-without-any-yield-or-sleep)*

Comment: But this is not a recommendation for OP to do this, right?